# Health bar in roblox studio has a different size when a script is ran

Tags: roblox

I made a health bar consisting of a health bar frame and a red bar childed inside of it. i then had a localscript in the healthbarframes parent folder that had this code.

This code is meant to lower the health bar depending on the amount of health the character has. But this happened instead.

[health bar glitch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhl5k.png)

```
-- Disable the healthbar
game.StarterGui:SetCoreGuiEnabled(Enum.CoreGuiType.Health,false)

--Variables
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local char = player.Character or player.CharacterAdded:Wait()

local HealthBarFrame = script.Parent:WaitForChild("HealthBarFrame")
-- Updating the healthbar
game:GetService("RunService").RenderStepped:Connect(function()
    local humanoid = char:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")
    HealthBarFrame.HealthBar.Size = UDim2.new(humanoid.Health/humanoid.MaxHealth,0,1,0)
end)
```